# CTC Formaker Air Printing

Tags: troubleshooting, mattercontrol

I have a CTC Formaker 4 in 1 3D Printer. It has worked great for a long while but now it is messing up. It will print fine for awhile and then the filament will stop coming out but the printer keeps moving like it thinks it is still printing. If I clear the print job and start over, it again prints fine at first but then I get the same end results. Please help me fix this problem. I have not been able to find a solution on Google.  Also I am using the latest version of MatterControl.

Comment: Welcome to SE 3D Printing! Have you verified your hot end is keeping heat? It could be the heating element is not keeping up. If, when you restart your print, the hot end is allowed to fully heat, it could start printing again without issue, then slowing down after the heat diminishes.

Comment: Help us help you! What is your expected behavior? Did you modify the machine? Is the filament getting ground to shreds? Is the temperature of your hotend holding? is your thermo-sensor and and heater cartridge properly seated? Are all the connectors to the bard properly set? are they working?

Comment: All of that checks out.  Everything was working fine and then this happened.  Nothing has been modified.  I just want to be able to get through a print.

Comment: Does this happen at the same point in the print every time? Is your head maintaining temperature? Is there friction on your delivery path?

Comment: It does not happen at the same point.  It usually prints for awhile then it does this.  I was printing a T-Rex skull last time and it almost got done when it stopped.  This last time is barely got started when it stopped.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a clogged nozzle. Try driving the filament into the hot end manually to verify that the plastic is flowing correctly. If there is a clog or other impediment in the nozzle, the filament will become curly as it is exiting the nozzle. A clear nozzle will always result in the filament extruding as one straight piece.

Comment: it might be this or anything else - the question is not clear enough...

Comment: The nozzle is not clogged, the filament extrudes in a straight piece.  The temperature is all fine. It does stop extruding at the same point each time even though the extruder is moving like it is still printing.  In each print, there is more layers on one side of the print than on the other sides.  Just so you know I am trying to print the AstroPie case parts.  The first one that I printed was the base and it printed fine.  Then I started having the problem when I started to print the heatsink.

Comment: Increase the print temp.